# Module not found: Can't resolve 'google-maps-react' in 'C:\Users\USUARIO

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a project in react that shows a google map with different locations.

I used: `$ npm install --save google-map-react` from this very simple tutorial that I found online: https://dev.to/jessicabetts/how-to-use-google-maps-api-and-react-js-26c2.

But later I realized that there are 2 similar npm install:

1. save google-map-react
2. save google-maps-react

I am so confused! I always get the same error:

```
./src/components/MapContainer.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'google-maps-react' in 'C:\Users\USUARIO\OneDrive\Escritorio\ProyectosGA\react-geek\packyfood\src\components'
```

I have no idea how to solve it and there is no much info. Could you guys please help me? Here is my code:

**MapContainer.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';

const mapStyles = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%'
};

export class MapContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={4}
        style={mapStyles}
        initialCenter={{
         lat: 6.2518401,
         lng: -75.563591
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyDGArUEBa5ns09IA7nt7jP-xfNIUkToFts'
})(MapContainer);
```

Answer (score 3):

Based off the tutorial it looks like you've missed a crucial step.

You need to install `google-maps-react` dependency in your project.

In your console, navigate to your project root directory and run the following:

```
npm install --save google-maps-react
```

Another troubleshooting issue for those who are stuck is to DELETE your `node_modules` folder and the run `npm install` in the console.

This will reinstall all the required dependencies for your project.

---

**Note:**

Considering you've accidentally installed `google-map-react` instead of `google-maps-react`. I recommend uninstalling `google-map-react` since it's not being used.

Do that by run the following in your console:

```
npm uninstall --save google-map-react
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by adding  `declare module 'google-map-react'`; in file `react-app-env.d.ts`

Try it out and give a feedback by the way I am using TS with React